# Fetch all the contacts that has no name associated with it using Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, cncontact, cncontactstore

I want to fetch all contacts stored that has no names on it. The below method helps me to search for all the contacts with string passed. I tried to pass empty string to find all contacts with no name, it didn't work.

```
func fetchContactsWithNoName() {

    let contactStore = CNContactStore()
    // Get all the containers
    var allContainers: [CNContainer] = []
    do {
        allContainers = try contactStore.containers(matching: nil)
    } catch {
        print("Error fetching containers")
    }

    // Iterate all containers and append their contacts to our results array
    for _ in allContainers {
      //  let fetchPredicate = CNContact.predicateForContactsInContainer(withIdentifier: container.identifier)

        do {
            let containerResults =  try contactStore.unifiedContacts(matching: CNContact.predicateForContacts(matchingName: " "), keysToFetch:[CNContactGivenNameKey as CNKeyDescriptor, CNContactFamilyNameKey as CNKeyDescriptor])
            self.results.append(contentsOf: containerResults)

        } catch {
            print("Error fetching results for container")
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to match a string which contains a single space, not an empty string. Is that intentional?

Comment: Nope my purpose is to find contacts which does not have name

Comment: try as " nil " or character.count == 0

Comment: @Warrior just as John said, try checking nil and zero length strings instead and I think you'll have the desired result